# How to transfer BRC-20 token from one wallet to another in React JS

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

I am researching on this topic since long, but didn't get the solution. Looking for someone to help me with the code.

Here is what i have found till now:

1. Its a two step process, first we can inscribe a transfer function using unisat wallet
2. then we need to send the inscription to the other person. Now i am stuck at this step, on how to do it

Sharing some resources which might be helpful:

1. https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib
2. https://github.com/unisat-wallet/wallet-sdk/blob/master/src/tx-helpers/send-inscription.ts
3. https://domo-2.gitbook.io/brc-20-experiment/
4. https://docs.unisat.io/dev/unisat-developer-service/unisat-inscribe/create-brc-20-transfer

Answer (score 0):

Inscription is just a special UTXO. Normally an inscription in BRC20 is an UTXO which has a value of 546 sats.

After creating inscription, sending it to other wallet is just like a normal transfering transaction with some attention to the order and value of inputs and outputs.

Here's an example

Inputs:

- Inscription UTXO (546 sats) from the sender
- A normal UTXO (to pay the transaction fee) from the sender

Outputs:

- Output #1: 546 sats to the recipient (this's the inscription)
- Output #2: change amount (after fee) to the sender

The order of the inscription needs to stay the same in the list of inputs and outputs.